# Looking for a way to calculate aggregates without collapsing rows

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

As the title says, I'd like to find an efficient way to calculate aggregates over groups of rows without collapsing those rows together. For an example I want to create the `mean` column in the table below.

```
|------------|---------|-------------|
|  category  |  value  | mean(value) |
|------------|---------|-------------|
|      A     |    1    |      3      |
|------------|---------|-------------|
|      A     |    3    |      3      |
|------------|---------|-------------|
|      A     |    5    |      3      |
|------------|---------|-------------|
|      B     |    1    |     1.5     |
|------------|---------|-------------|
|      B     |    2    |     1.5     |
|------------|---------|-------------|
```

So far, the best way I've found to do this is:

```
T
| join kind=leftouter (T | summarize avg() by category) on category
```

This seems to be causing performance problems. I'm also aware of a way of doing it using `partition by`, but need to support having more than 64 categories.

Am I missing a good way of doing this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
let MyTable = datatable(Category:string, value:long) [
   "A", 1,
   "A", 3,
   "A", 5,
   "B", 1,
   "B", 2
];
let Avgs = MyTable | summarize avg(value) by Category;
MyTable | lookup (Avgs) on Category
```

This will output exactly what you want.

Explanation:

1. First you create a temporary table (using a `let` statement) named `Avgs`, where you'll have the average per Category.
2. Your main statement is to output `MyTable`, but for every category you want to also display the relevant value from `Avgs`, which you achieve by using the `lookup` operator.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: It seems to run about 10% faster than my version. Still interested in other ideas, if anyone has any.